# Selecting from another table based on relation tables value

Tags: php, mysql, banking

I have three tables in MySQL:

1) **bank_accounts**

```
- accounts_id (PRIMARY)
- accounts_account_number (UNIQUE)
```

2) **bank_accounts_customers**

```
- accounts_customers_id (PRIMARY)
- accounts_customers_account_id (INDEX)
- accounts_customers_customer_id (INDEX)
```

3) **bank_customers**

```
- customers_id (PRIMARY)
- customers_customer_number (UNIQUE)
- customers_title
- customers_first_name
- customers_middle_name
- customers_last_name
```

I need to get the Account Number stored in the **bank_accounts** table and the Customer Number stored in the **bank_customer** table. The table **bank_accounts_customers** stores a link between the customers and the accounts that they have so multiple customers can share one account. All tables in the database are indexed and using Foreign Keys to link them.

Im unsure if *INNER JOIN* or *JOIN* would work and how to do this?

I have attached an image of the database (that is not 100% complete).
https://s32.postimg.org/ia56fgjth/Screen_Shot_2016_07_31_at_5_51_38_pm.png

The query that I have tried is:

```
SELECT `bank_accounts`.`accounts_account_number`, `bank_customers`.`customers_customer_number`
FROM `bank_accounts`, `bank_customers`
INNER JOIN `bank_accounts_customers`
ON bank_accounts_customers`.`accounts_customers_account_id` = `bank_accounts`.`accounts_id`
```

Comment: If possible, show the query. We are here to help if you faced any problem.

Comment: So joins sounds about right...what have you tried? Or 0 effort and just askin'?

Comment: Sorry, @FirstOne i'm just unsure how to use them within this project.

Comment: @BradTurner Use the EDIT link below the question. Code posted in the comments section is unreadable. Then you may remove your 2 last comments.

Comment: Edit your question and add your query to it so it is well formatted

Comment: Update the post with the query. Any error in the query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT ba.accounts_account_number, bc.customers_customer_number 
FROM bank_accounts AS ba

INNER JOIN bank_accounts_customers AS bac
 ON bac.accounts_customers_account_id = ba.accounts_id

INNER JOIN bank_customers AS bc
 ON bc.customers_id = bac.accounts_customers_customer_id
```

Should get what you want.

Answer (score 0):

```
select 
ba.accounts_account_number, 
bc.customers_title,bc.customers_first_name, bc.customers_middle_name, bc.customers_last_name 
from bank_accounts ba inner join bank_accounts_customers bac 
on ba.accounts_id = bac.accounts_customers_account_id 
inner join bank_customers bc 
on bac.accounts_customers_customer_id = bc.customers_id
```

Try this..!!

Comment: Thanks @Vinit Prajapati!

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
SELECT ba.accounts_account_number, bc.customers_customer_number 
FROM bank_accounts_customers bac
INNER JOIN bank_accounts ba on bac.accounts_customers_account_id = ba.accounts_id
INNER JOIN bank_customers bc on bac.accounts_customers_customer_id = bc.customers_id
```